# Sort the rows of a 2d array by a column

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have associative array. On print_f($array_name), I got this

```
Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [teamid] => abc
            [distance] => 1.25
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [teamid] => xyz
            [distance] => 0.25
        )
    )
```

This is that array which I want to sort according to **distance**. eg, This should be look like this after sorting,

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [teamid] => xyz
        [distance] => 0.25
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [teamid] => abc
        [distance] => 1.25
    )
)
```

If anyone know answer then please explain or suggest me link from where I can understand from beginning. Thank You.

Comment: Your link is http://php.net/usort

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need to do.

```
$a = array(array( 'teamid' => 'abc', 'distance' => 1.25 ), array( 'teamid' => 'xyz', 'distance' => 0.25 ));

$distance = array();
foreach ($a as $key => $row)
{
    $distance[$key] = $row['distance'];
}
array_multisort($distance, SORT_ASC, $a);

print_r($a);
```

This outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [teamid] => xyz
            [distance] => 0.25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [teamid] => abc
            [distance] => 1.25
        )

)
```

**[source](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)** *Example #3 Sorting database results*

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/dCRJPU)**

**Edit**

as per **Mike's** comment,

**[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013974/php-usort-or-array-multisort)** are two answers,
one tells that on single `array` you should use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort)(as Mike's answer) and [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array_multisort) is used to compare elements from different arrays (or sub-arrays) at the same time.

in the other answer, as Mike wants some bench marking

> usort() is more concise and doesn't require extracting a column array to feed to array_multisort(). (It also does less than array_multisort.)
>
> However, when I repeatedly tested it today on arrays of 20,000 and
> 10,000 representative data rows, **usort()** was 7-15x slower than
> **array_multisort()** when the column was random values of type int and
> the column was pre-extracted. That is as one might expect, since for
> every comparison you're comparing an entire php function call to
> optimized intrinsic code.

more about bench marking notes, read full **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23004507/2558525)**

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the benchmark between `array_multisort` and `usort` (like I suggest in my separate answer). I think OP would be better off skipping the extra `foreach` loop that's required with `array_multisort` like you've suggested.

Comment: thanks for following up, some interesting info there!

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    array('teamid' => 'a', 'distance' => 1.25),
    array('teamid' => 'b', 'distance' => 0.25),
    array('teamid' => 'c', 'distance' => 2.5),
    array('teamid' => 'd', 'distance' => 0.75),
);


function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['distance'] == $b['distance']) return 0;
    return ($a['distance'] < $b['distance']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

More info: http://php.net/usort

Comment: updating my answer. :)